# Importing derived classes can only import one

Tags: c++

How do I import multiple derived class headers (without receiving errors)?

I have a base class Ship. I have 2 derived classes, cargoship and cruiseship. In my main class, I attempt to import the header files for both cargoship and cruiseship. If I import both, I get an error; if I import one, no errors.

My attempts at multiple imports:

```
include "CruiseShip.h"
include "Cargoship.h"
```

The error list:

```
1>c:\users\cory\source\repos\project33\project33\ship.h(7): error C2011: 'Ship': 'class' type redefinition
1>c:\users\cory\source\repos\project33\project33\ship.h(7): note: see declaration of 'Ship'
1>c:\users\cory\source\repos\project33\project33\cargoship.h(7): error C2504: 'Ship': base class undefined
```

My ship base class:

```
#include "Ship.h"

Ship::Ship() {
}
 Ship::~Ship() {
 }

Ship::Ship(string name, string year) : shipName(name), shipYear(year) {

 }

string Ship::getShipName() {
 return shipName;
}
string Ship::getShipYear() {
 return shipYear;
}

 void Ship::setShipName(string name) {
  shipName = name;
}

void Ship::setShipYear(string year) {
 shipYear = year;
 }

 string Ship::print() const {
 return "Ship Name: " + shipName + " \nYear Built: " + shipYear;
}
```

Comment: It looks very possible that you're not using include guards, which should be explained in any teaching material about header files. Naturally, it's hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @chris thank you very much for pointing that out. It solved the issue. stupid professor didn't teach us this.

Answer (score -1):

Was not using include guards on the base class header file:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard